# How to subtrace a date in label.text from a datetimepicker.value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetimepicker

```
Dim x = dtpextend.Value - lblcheckoutdate.Text
Dim day = x.TotalDays
Dim y As Integer = Day + Val(1)
formPaymentforextend.lbldayextend.Text = y
```

The first row throws an error:

> Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'String'

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the string to `DateTime`. Example:

```
Dim x = dtpextend.Value - DateTime.Parse(lblcheckoutdate.Text)
```

You can also use other ways to do the conversion like `DateTime.ParseExact()`, `DateTime.TryParse()`, `Convert.ToDateTime()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the two dates to the same format before computing the difference. I would recommend that you convert them to epoch time by using the below function and then compute the difference.

```
function date2epoch(myDate)
date2epoch = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", myDate)
end function
```

Or try converting them to DateTime object like:
    cDate(lblcheckoutdate.Text)